# DHCP server assigining wrong IP address

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, vlan

I have a strange problem with a few laptops. I noticed that all of a sudden  one laptop stopped getting ethernet connection. It managed to get an IP with all the rest of the info (subnet, DNS servers, etc), but it is from the IT office VLAN. The building that the laptop is in is another vlan and the switch port has the correct vlan assigned for that building for pc users. The connection details show receiving data packets, but not sending.

One of the errors that showed up on the event viewer that caught my eye was the following:

```
The server could not bind to the transport \Device\NetBT_Tcpip (xxxx) because another computer on the network has the same name. The server could not start.
```

And this one:

```
The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRS) for network adapter with settings:

Adapter Name: (xxxx) Host Name: xxxx

Primary Domain Suffix xxxxx

DNS server list:

10.1.2.110, 10.1.2.113

Sent update to server: <?>

IP Address(es):

10.1.200.222

The reason the system could not register these RRS was because the update request it sent to the DNS server timed out. The most likely cause of this is that the DNS server authoritative for the name it was attempting to register or update is not running at this time.

You can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing ipconfig /registerns' at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator.

The DHCP entry was deleted, but keeps pulling up the wrong vlan IP.
```

So far it only connects fine at our building for some strange reason, but with a totally different vlan Ip.

Comment: DHCP is a broadcast service... the device sends out a request and gets and offer back from the DHCP server... it doesn't pick an IP address to get. This is a network issue, likely network helper on a misconfigured switch, or a DHCP server problem. I would suggest talking to the IT dept on campus.

Comment: Yeah, if you have separate DHCP servers in each VLAN and those machines are somehow managing to broadcast a DHCP request and receive a response from a DHCP server on the wrong VLAN then I'd suspect a networking issue. If DHCP is failing to start on the correct server, that could also suggest that since it may be seeing the other DHCP server (when it shouldn't be able to) and stopping since there's another DHCP already running on the visible network.

Comment: The odd thing is that it is only occurring on just one or 2 laptops. The rest are fine. Should the IP helper on that swiych for that VLAN building point to the main DHCP server?

Comment: @acejavelin I understand that the DHCP server gives an gives an IP from within the scope unless it is already reserved. Not sure why it is assigning from the wrong scope. Hence why it doesn't receive any packets, since it is on the wrong VLAN that is not set on the port. I wonder if I change the port's VLAN to the other building's if it will communicate.

Comment: I can't answer that... but something is wrong, either in the scope configuration or the networking itself. I would suggest opening a ticket with your network/IT support organization.